# Modifying the output of the jekyll-amazon tag

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I am using the [jekyll-amazon gem](https://github.com/tokzk/jekyll-amazon) in my Jekyll site successfully, but I would like to modify the output of the detail tag.  Right now it does:

```
      def detail(item)
        attrs = {
          author: item[:author],
          publisher: item[:publisher],
          date: item[:publication_date] || item[:release_date],
          salesrank: item[:salesrank],
          description: br2nl(item[:description])
        }.map { |k, v| ItemAttribute.new(k, v).to_html }.join("\n")

        str = <<-"EOS"
<div class="jk-amazon-item">
  #{image(item)}
  <div class="jk-amazon-info">
    #{title(item)}
    #{attrs}
  </div>
</div>
        EOS
        str.to_s
      end
```

but I would like to remove publisher, date, salesrank and description from the list of attributes.  Can I override this method, or change the attrs list, and if so, how?

I tried the technique of putting a file in config/initializers containing the override code but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: You can't, as those methods are private. You need to patch the source yourself or file a feature request with the gem maintainer.

Comment: LOL what a rookie mistake.  Thanks.  Please create an answer so I can give you the points.  I did file an issue with the maintainer.

Comment: I'll be watching the issue as well, but feel free to edit my answer if changes  do happen. Good luck.

Comment: I am working out the details of making this change myself (which I will submit to the maintainer as a PR).  I'm pretty close to a complete solution; you can see the details in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567687/how-do-i-monkey-patch-a-jekyll-extension-or-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.3.0 supports [custom templates](https://github.com/tokzk/jekyll-amazon/issues/6#issuecomment-272414510):

> _config.yml:
>
> ```
> jekyll-amazon:
>   template_dir: '_templates'
> ```
>
> _templates/detail.erb:
>
> ```
> <a href="<%= item[:detail_page_url] %>" target="_blank">
>   <%= item[:title] %> / <%= item[:author] %>
> </a>
> ```