# How do I monkey-patch a Jekyll extension or plugin?

Tags: plugins, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'd like to override a gem method (a Jekyll extension) that looks like this:

File: [`lib/jekyll-amazon/amazon_tag.rb`](https://github.com/tokzk/jekyll-amazon/blob/8fd9d9ff676e7e1dedd18755e5d0d98300f9e3fc/lib/jekyll-amazon/amazon_tag.rb).

```
module Jekyll
  module Amazon
    class AmazonTag < Liquid::Tag
      def detail(item)
...
      end
    end
  end
end
Liquid::Template.register_tag('amazon', Jekyll::Amazon::AmazonTag)
```

I have placed code with the same structure in my project in the folder <strike>`config/initializers/presentation.rb`</strike> `_plugins/presentation.rb`.  If I change the name of the method `detail` to a new name, it works, but I can't get it to override the name `detail`.
What have I done wrong?

(Note: In version 0.2.2 of the jekyll-amazon gem, the `detail` method is private; I have changed this locally so that the method is no longer private.)

Comment: Looks like we got lucky: jekyll-amazon now supports [custom templates](https://github.com/tokzk/jekyll-amazon/issues/6).

Comment: Yes, but I still want to know (for my own knowledge) how to override the original gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [alias_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-alias_method)

```
module Jekyll
  module Amazon
    class AmazonTag < Liquid::Tag

      alias_method :old_detail, :detail

      def detail(item)
        # do your stuff here
        # eventually pass your stuff to old method
        old_detail(item)
      end

    end
  end
end
Liquid::Template.register_tag('amazon', Jekyll::Amazon::AmazonTag)
```

Comment: put it at the root of your jekyll site in a `_plugins` folder

Comment: I'm getting `jekyll 3.3.1 | Error:  undefined method 'detail' for class Jekyll::Amazon::AmazonTag`

Comment: My _config.yml has `gems: ['jekyll-paginate', 'jekyll-amazon']`, and I see the base plugin I am overriding when I do a `gem list`.

Comment: If I use `new_detail` rather than `detail` in `_plugins/presentation.rb` and update my html to use this new tag, it works.  But I can't seem to "override" the old `detail` tag.

Comment: Marking this as correct because I think this the closest you can get.